# ibatis use IN instead of OR

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I have following query in my sql mapping file, it is using OR in the generated SQL query for FIELD3. It is a `List` of `Integer`

```
<select id="myCriteria" parameterClass="mySearchCriteria" resultMap="generated_MyResult">
        select * from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.FIELD1 = 1
        <dynamic>
            <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field2">
                MY_TABLE.FIELD2 = $field2$
            </isNotNull>

            <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field3_list">
                <iterate close=")" conjunction="or" open="(" property="meIds">
                    MY_TABLE.FIELD3= $field3_list[]$
                </iterate>
            </isNotNull>
        </dynamic>
    </select>
```

If I want to use IN instead of OR , `iterate` is removed, the below will work?

```
<select id="myCriteria" parameterClass="mySearchCriteria" resultMap="generated_MyResult">
        select * from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.FIELD1 = 1
        <dynamic>
            <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field2">
                MY_TABLE.FIELD2 = $field2$
            </isNotNull>

            <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field3_list">

                    MY_TABLE.FIELD3 IN $field3_list[]$

            </isNotNull>
        </dynamic>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a IN clause, i would keep iterate element:

```
<select id="myCriteria" parameterClass="mySearchCriteria" resultMap="generated_MyResult">
    select * from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.FIELD1 = 1
    <dynamic>
        <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field2">
            MY_TABLE.FIELD2 = #field2#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotEmpty prepend="and" property="field3_list">
            MY_TABLE.FIELD3 IN
            <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," property="field3_list">
                #field3_list[]#
            </iterate>
        </isNotEmpty>
    </dynamic>
</select>
```

Or, if you are sure that you field3_list is never null:

```
<select id="myCriteria" parameterClass="mySearchCriteria" resultMap="generated_MyResult">
    select * from MY_TABLE where MY_TABLE.FIELD1 = 1
    <dynamic>
        <isNotNull prepend="and" property="field2">
            MY_TABLE.FIELD2 = #field2#
        </isNotNull>
        <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," property="field3_list" prepend="AND MY_TABLE.FIELD3 IN">
            #field3_list[]#
        </iterate>
    </dynamic>
</select>
```

Also, I switched your parameters from $xx$ (which refers to table name) to #xx#

Comment: `isNotEmpty` also checks for `isNotNull` internally?

Comment: Yes, from the doc: `Checks to see if the value of a Collection, String property is not null and not empty ("" or size() < 1).` (https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf)